# Angular 2 - How to have an `svg` in app.component and a `circle` as a child component?

Tags: angular, svg

So I want to develop a Pac-man game using Angular, I want to use an **SVG** for this, I want to create the `board.component` which will have an embedded `pacman.component`.

`board.component` will have an `<svg></svg>` and `pacman.component` will have a `<circle></circle>` but angular throws this error in my `pacman.component`:

[Angular] 'circle' is not a known element :

> 1. If '**circle**' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. To allow any element add '**NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA**' to the '**@NgModule.schemas**' of this component.

After fixing those errors I end up with this **SVG**:

```
  <svg _ngcontent-c0="" width="100" height="100">
    <app-pacman _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1="">
      <circle _ngcontent-c1="" fill="yellow" r="25" cx="10" cy="10"></circle>
    </app-pacman>
  </svg>
```

Now the only problem now is that angular wraps the `pacman.component` with `<app-pacman></app-pacman>` and that makes the `circle` not work.

Just wondering what would be the Angular way of doing this? I don't want to have my whole `svg` code `(svg, circles, paths, etc...)` in a single component.

Thanks.

Edit:

`board.component.html`:

```
<svg [attr.width]="width" [attr.height]="height">
  <app-pacman></app-pacman>
</svg>
```

`pacman.component.html`:

```
<circle [attr.cx]="cx" [attr.cy]="cy" r="25" fill="yellow"></circle>
```

Comment: Post your component class code

Comment: Post the both components templates please

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe answer to your question described in this wonderfull article: https://teropa.info/blog/2016/12/12/graphics-in-angular-2.html#avoiding-element-selectors-for-components

In short, you need to use your child component as attribute instead of element (you can do this because @Component decorator derived from @Directive).
Applying to your case, it would look like this:

In board.component.html:

```
<svg [attr.width]="width" [attr.height]="height">
    <svg:g app-pacman />
</svg>
```

In pacman.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: '[app-pacman]',
    templateUrl: ...
})
...
```

Comment: Yes!, this does it.

Comment: Note that the selector is in brackets, so `'[app-pacman]'` as opposed to the normal `'app-pacman'`.

Answer (score 1):

I would think you would want to do something like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'svg-component',
    template: `
        <svg>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </svg>
    `
})
export class SvgComponent {}

import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'circle-component',
    template: `
        <ng-container>
            <circle></circle>
        </ng-container>
    `
})
export class CircleComponent {}
```

Comment: But how do I put the `CircleComponent` inside the `SvgComponent` without it having a `<circle-component></circle-component>` wrapper?

Comment: Did you try it? that is what the `ng-content` `ng-container` syntax is for.

Comment: Yeah, I get a `[Angular] <ng-content> element cannot have content.` and a `[Angular] <ng-content> element cannot have content.` error.

I tried doing: `<ng-content><app-pacman></app-pacman></ng-content>` and `<ng-content><circle [attr.cx]="cx" [attr.cy]="cy" r="25" fill="yellow"></circle></ng-content>`

Comment: My bad, I switched `ng-content` and `ng-container`. I tried doing: `<svg [attr.width]="width" [attr.height]="height"><circle-component></circle-component><ng-content></ng-content></svg>` and `<ng-container><circle [attr.cx]="cx" [attr.cy]="cy" r="25" fill="yellow"></circle></ng-container>` but angular still adds a `<circle-component></circle-component>`. Do I need to do this with transclusion?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://plnkr.co/edit/m8PX2UizgmNL2oUdMxhE?p=preview?

Comment: Yeah but I want the `circle` to be it's own component.

Answer (score 0):

The SVG Namespace is very strict. I think browsers will reject an svg outright if it contains unknown elements. This is one of the reasons injecting svg's into the DOM directly as raw markup is relatively (but still not very) safer than injecting other types of markup. I work with svg's a lot in angular, but come to think of it, I don't think I've ever tried to separate their parts into different angular components. You could try using different selectors for your components, like class or attribute selectors applied to regular svg elements. That could work.

I do know directives work just fine. Nearly all my  and  elements have associated directives. I would try accomplishing what you need with directives - they can each hold instance data/properties for their host, similar to a component, the only difference would be the view is all encapsulated in one parent component. You can use dependency injection to inject the host / parent component into all of the child directive instances, or use @ViewChildren to query for all of the child directive instances and manipulate them from the component.

If you need to arbitrarily group elements together, you can use the svg group element

```
    <g> ... </g>
```

or you could use angular's 'invisible' container,

```
  <ng-container>...</ng-container>
```

if all you need to do is iterate over some list or apply an ngIf statement, etc.

Comment: Browsers don't reject SVG unless its served as XML in which case the XML parser may reject it. Browsers (per the SVG specification) should not display unknown elements in the SVG namespace or unknown elements (in any namespace) that are children of known SVG elements.

Comment: good to know. I guess the angular/typescript compiler will reject them, then. It seems that the unknown element breaks the namespace.

Answer (score 0):

I think the compiler error `[Angular] 'circle' is not a known element` is the point. Just add `svg` prefix to `circle`.

```
<div [ngSwitch]="prop?.type">
    <app-svg-circle *ngSwitchCase="'circle'" [props]="prop"></app-svg-circle>
    <svg:path *ngSwitchCase="'path'" prop="prop"></svg:path>
</div>


@Component({
    selector: 'app-svg-base',
    template: `
            <svg:circle ${SvgBaseComponent.Bindings}></svg:circle>
    `
    })
    export class SvgBaseComponent {
      @Input()
      public props;
      public static readonly Bindings = '[attr.x]="props?.x" [attr.y]="props?.y" [attr.stroke]="props?.stroke"'

    }


@Component({
    selector: 'app-svg-circle',
    template: `
            <svg:circle ${SvgBaseComponent.Bindings}></svg:circle>
    `
    })
    export class SvgCircleComponent extends SvgBaseComponent { }
```